# Read the Messages which are posted to other application like spy++ but from the code

Tags: winapi, spy++, deviare

We have an application which will get the messages from the device level . Now we want to create a tool which can track the messages which are posted to the original application

Is there any way we can develop as similar to spy++ . I have searched for spy++ sdk but didnt find anywhere

Comment: *"messages from the device level"* - What sort of messages are you referring to?

Comment: Device driver will post the messages to the application window

Comment: This is a fairly fuzzy description. A kernel-mode device driver doesn't know anything about windows or applications. What do you really need help with?

Comment: Window messages can be intercepted using `SetWindowsHookEx()`.  The hook callback will tell you which window each message belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

Usually apps communicates with device drivers using `CreateFile` and `DeviceIoControl`. Try hooking them.